# how to toggle an 'active' class but also hide it when clicked again

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list item menu which when I click the current `li` it toggles the `.active` class and makes the background green. However when I click another `li` it still shows the green background for the previous li that was clicked. How do I make it so that when an item is clicked, it toggles its background when clicked but also removes it when another li is clicked?

```
<ul class="menu-wrapper">
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$(".template-in-conversation .js-accordion-header").on("click", function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings("a").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: They are not siblings of the selector specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$(this)` in the context of your handler is the anchor, and when you call `.siblings()` on it you get no siblings, because the anchor has no siblings inside of the parent `<li/>` that contains it.  Instead, you can navigate to the parent, get the siblings from there, then target the anchor inside of it:

```js
$(".template-in-conversation .js-accordion-header").on("click", function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-wrapper template-in-conversation">
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery for this trivial task. Just use `element.classList.toggle('active', bool)`. No need to fumble around with siblings etc.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.js-accordion-header');
document.querySelector('.menu-wrapper').addEventListener(
  'click', 
  ({target}) => {
    for (const item of items) item.classList.toggle('active', target === item);
  }
);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-wrapper">
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The second parameter decides whether `toggle` acts as `add` (if the boolean is `true`) or `remove` (if the boolean is `false`):

```
target === item
```

The goal is simply achieved by answering the question "Was the element clicked the one that is currently iterated?". If yes, add the class, if not, remove it.

If you also need to allow toggling an already active element off by clicking it again, you need to expand the condition:

```
target === item && !target.classList.contains('active')
```

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.js-accordion-header');
document.querySelector('.menu-wrapper').addEventListener(
  'click', 
  ({target}) => {
    for (const item of items) {
      item.classList.toggle('active', target === item && !target.classList.contains('active'));
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-wrapper">
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Definitely like the non ```jQuery``` approach, but you're missing toggling class when clicking the same item.

Comment: I don't think OP asked for that.

Comment: I believe that's what the title says: how to toggle an 'active' class but also hide it when clicked again

Comment: Added a second version that expands the condition so it does toggle an already active item off as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your input with this, @Alexander's solution worked perfectly for me

Comment: I can only recommend to stop using jQuery for this stuff. The DOM API is much faster and it's built-in. In many cases (like this one) it's also much more consise.

Answer (score 1):

The anchors are not siblings of each other, the solution is to go up to the `ul` using `parents()` and then find all `a` in that `ul`

```js
$(() => {
  $(".js-accordion-header").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents("ul").find("a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-wrapper">
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Beat me by _20 seconds_... well played :P  Also your solution is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @AlexanderNied, this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to also toggle the same clicked element, you can do something like this:

```js
$(".template-in-conversation .js-accordion-header").on("click", function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-wrapper template-in-conversation">
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="js-accordion-header">item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Adson, sorry I am nee here but I will keep this in mind in future.